# Using variables with nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this:

```
var a = { A : { AA : 1 }, B : 2 };
```

Is there a way for me to create a variable that could allow me to reference either AA or B? What would the syntax look like?

```
// I know I can do this:    
a['B']; // 2
a['A']['AA']; // 1

// something like this?
var myRef = ???;
a[myRef]; 1 or 2 depending on myRef
```

If not, what's a better way to get what I'm going for here?

Comment: What is the context? Why don't you assign the value of either `a['A']['AA']` or `a['B']` to a variable? Is `myref` changing over time? But no, it is not possible that way, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6906859/218196) probably helps you.

Comment: I was receiving a nested JSON response that I wanted to be able to sort by its various fields.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not directly.

### Solution 1 - use object flattening

Flatten object, to have new object `var a = { 'A.AA' : 1; B : 2 };`.

See [compressing object hierarchies in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963607/compressing-object-hierarchies-in-javascript)
or [Flattening a complex json object for mvc binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210437/flattening-a-complex-json-object-for-mvc-binding) to get the javascript function for it.

### Soution 2 - write key-path accessor

I can see it was already addressed by Eugen.
Reposted code-reviewed version:

```
function Leaf(obj,path) {
  path=path.split('.');
  var res=obj;
  for (var i=0;i<path.length;i++) res=res[path[i]];
  return res;
}
```

### Solution 3 - use eval

```
var x = eval("a." + myRef); // x will be 1 for myRef == "A.AA", 2 for "B"
```

Be careful with this solution as you may introduce some security issues. It is more of the curiosity.

Comment: eval would also be prone to turning off optimizations and screw with performance all around.

Comment: Thanks. This led me to my solution. I looked in google closure (which I am using) for an accessor on the Object type. They have this method: goog.object.getValueByKeys(obj, Array | number | string | undefined) so myRef can be ['A', 'AA'] or ['B'] (if I want to consistently pass an array). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: #solution #3 saved my day @Krizz Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Since i also encounter this problem, i wrote also a one line util for this (ES6):

```
const leaf = (obj, path) => (path.split('.').reduce((value,el) => value[el], obj))
```

Example:

```
const objSample = { owner: { name: 'Neo' } };
const pathSample = 'owner.name';

leaf(objSample, pathSample) //'Neo'
```

Comment: Love this answer. One small tweak:
const leaf = (obj, path) => (path.split('.').reduce((value,el) => value && value[el], obj))

Comment: Thanks! Wanted to avoid lodash in this case and this works nicely :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function Leaf(obj,path) {
  path=path.split('.');
  var res=obj;
  for (var i=0;i<path.length;i++) obj=obj[path[i]];
  return res;
}
```

Leaf(a,'B')=2

Leaf(a,'A.AA')=1

Decorate with error handling etc. according to your needs.

Comment: -1 There were enough problems with this snippet to warrant a downvote. Besides the spelling of length and the caps on split and length, it is currently just returning the original object that was passed in. `obj=obj[path[i]]` should be `res=res[path[i]]`. http://jsfiddle.net/QuVdr/

Comment: Duely noted - tried to vote myself down, but this isn't supported by SO. Answer not deleted for historical reasons, as it is quoted in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

With lodash _.get function, you can access nested properties with dot syntax.

Node server-side example:

```
const _ = require('lodash'); 

let item = { a: {b:'AA'}};

 _.get(item, 'a.b');
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually no, because js object are seen as property bags and doing `a[X]` is for accessing first level properties only...

But you could wrap the logic  `a['A']['AA']; // 1` in a function that does the same, like this

```
//WARN... no undefined check here => todo !
function _(o, path) {
  var tmp = o
  for (var i=0 ; i < path.length ; i++) {
    tmp = tmp[path[i]]
  }
  return tmp
}

var r = _(a, ['A', 'AA'])
```

This is pretty much the same as other answers, but the difference is when dummy boy create object property name containing dots... Like `var a = {"a.a" : 3 }` is valid.

Now, such problem would occurs maybe more often now with the help of IndexedDB to store anything locally...