# Covert JS object into flat array with parent names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, parent

I have an object like this:

```
data:
{
    connection:
    {
        type: 0,
        connected: false
    },
    acceleration:
    {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
        watchId: 0,
        hasError: false
    }        
},
```

Converting it to flat array like this:

```
"connected": false
"hasError": false
"type": 0
"watchId": 0
"x": 0
"y": 0
"z": 0
```

is an easy task (recurrence is your friend!).

But is there any way in  Javascript to get it with so called *full parents*, i.e. something like this:

```
"connection.connected": false
"acceleration.hasError": false
"connection.type": 0
"acceleration.watchId": 0
"acceleration.x": 0
"acceleration.y": 0
"acceleration.z": 0
```

Or am I expecting to much?

Comment: There is no reason that such code could not be written.

Comment: Sure, as you said recurrence[sic] is your friend. Just pass forward the current property name appended to the previous as a string.

Comment: This should be EASIER than what you've already done, since you won't have to iterate over the internal objects' properties. You're going from an object full of objects to an array full of _the same_ objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compressing object hierarchies in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963607/compressing-object-hierarchies-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another variant:

```
function flatten(o) {
  var prefix = arguments[1] || "", out = arguments[2] || {}, name;
  for (name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      typeof o[name] === "object" ? flatten(o[name], prefix + name + '.', out) : 
                                    out[prefix + name] = o[name];
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

invoke like `flatten(data);`

Answer (score 3):

There's always a way, but note that both of these are objects, neither is an array. (associative arrays in Javascript are just objects ).

```
function objectFlatten( o , n ) {
        var p   =   {}
            ,   n = n? n : ''
            ,   merge = function(a,b){ for( k in b) a[k] = b[k]; return a;}
            ;

        for( i in o ) {
            if( o.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) {
                if( Object.prototype.toString.call( o[i] ) == '[object Object]' || Object.prototype.toString.call( o[i] ) == '[object Array]')
                    p = merge( p , objectFlatten( o[i] , n? n + '.' + i : i ) );
                else
                    p[i] = o[i];

                }
            }

        return p;
   }
```

Comment: Note, this made the assumption that keeping array index keys was the right decision (which it probably isn't)

Comment: should your merge also check for hasOwnProperty? 
also merge doesnt really need to return anything since the a parameter will be being passed by reference (sorta).

Comment: You're right it probably doesn't need to return anything, and it should also probably use hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 2):

For posterity - check out [flat](https://github.com/hughsk/flat) or a similar utility I wrote for Forms JS, [Flatten](https://github.com/forms-js/forms-js/blob/master/source/utils/flatten.ts).

Answer (score 1):

My five cents.

For cases when you want flatten objects **but not properties**

In other words.

You have something like this:

```
var obj = {
  one_a: {
    second_a: {
      aaa: 'aaa',
      bbb: 'bbb'
    },
    second_b: {
      qqq: 'qqq',
      third_a: {
        www: 'www',
        eee: 'eee',
        fourth_a: {
          'rrr': 'rrr',
          fifth: {
            ttt: 'ttt'
          }
        },
        fourth_b: {
          yyy: 'yyy',
        }
      },
      third_b: {
        'uuu': 'uuu'
      }
    }
  },
  one_b: {
    iii: 'iii'
  }
}
```

And want to make nested object flat, but don't want to flat properties:

```
{ 'one_a second_a ': { aaa: 'aaa', bbb: 'bbb' },
  'one_a second_b ': { qqq: 'qqq' },
  'one_a second_b third_a ': { www: 'www', eee: 'eee' },
  'one_a second_b third_a fourth_a ': { rrr: 'rrr' },
  'one_a second_b third_a fourth_a fifth ': { ttt: 'ttt' },
  'one_a second_b third_a fourth_b ': { yyy: 'yyy' },
  'one_a second_b third_b ': { uuu: 'uuu' },
  'one_b ': { iii: 'iii' } }
```

Code:

```
function flatten (obj, includePrototype, into, prefix) {
  into = into || {};
  prefix = prefix || "";

  for (var k in obj) {
    if (includePrototype || obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      var prop = obj[k];
      if (prop && typeof prop === "object" && !(prop instanceof Date || prop instanceof RegExp)) {
        flatten(prop, includePrototype, into, prefix + k + " ");
      }
      else {
        if (into[prefix] && typeof into[prefix] === 'object') {
          into[prefix][k] = prop
        } else {
          into[prefix] = {}
          into[prefix][k] = prop
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return into;
}
```

Based on [closure's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18109677/930170)